# How do I move specific XElements to the previous node in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Following is my XML:

```
<navMap>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/01_Cover.xhtml"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/02_Titlepage.xhtml#Titlepage"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/03_Copyright.xhtml#Copyright"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/04_Contents.xhtml#Contents"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/05_Part01.xhtml#Part01"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint>
        <content src="Text/06_Part02.xhtml#Part02"/>
        <navPoint><content src="Text/06_Part02.xhtml#h3_2-1"/></navPoint>
        <navPoint>
            <content src="Text/08_Chapter01.xhtml#Chapter01"/>
            <navPoint><content src="Text/08_Chapter01.xhtml#h3_4-1"/></navPoint>
        </navPoint>
    </navPoint>
    <navPoint>
        <content src="Text/07_Part03.xhtml#Part03"/>
        <navPoint><content src="Text/07_Part03.xhtml#h3_3-1"/></navPoint>
    </navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/09_Chapter02.xhtml#Chapter02"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/10_Chapter03.xhtml#Chapter03"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/11_Chapter04.xhtml#Chapter04"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/12_Chapter05.xhtml#Chapter05"/></navPoint>
</navMap>
```

In this XML, all the `src` attributes containing `h3` is a child of it's respective parent and the rest are all separate elements.

Similarly, I want to move all the Chapters to its respective part elements, like:

```
<navMap>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/01_Cover.xhtml"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/02_Titlepage.xhtml#Titlepage"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/03_Copyright.xhtml#Copyright"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/04_Contents.xhtml#Contents"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint><content src="Text/05_Part01.xhtml#Part01"/></navPoint>
    <navPoint>
        <content src="Text/06_Part02.xhtml#Part02"/>
        <navPoint><content src="Text/06_Part02.xhtml#h3_2-1"/></navPoint>
        <navPoint>
            <content src="Text/08_Chapter01.xhtml#Chapter01"/>
            <navPoint><content src="Text/08_Chapter01.xhtml#h3_4-1"/></navPoint>
        </navPoint>
    </navPoint>
    <navPoint>
        <content src="Text/07_Part03.xhtml#Part03"/>
        <navPoint><content src="Text/07_Part03.xhtml#h3_3-1"/></navPoint>
        <navPoint><content src="Text/09_Chapter02.xhtml#Chapter02"/></navPoint>
        <navPoint><content src="Text/10_Chapter03.xhtml#Chapter03"/></navPoint>
        <navPoint><content src="Text/11_Chapter04.xhtml#Chapter04"/></navPoint>
        <navPoint><content src="Text/12_Chapter05.xhtml#Chapter05"/></navPoint>
    </navPoint>
</navMap>
```

I have given indents to explain my need. I thought of something like:

```
foreach (var element in xDoc.Root.Element("navMap").Elements())
{
    if (element.Element("content").Attribute("src").Value.Contains("_Chapter"))
    {
        var previousNode = element.PreviousNode;
        if (previousNode.Contains == "Part")
        {
            //Shift element to Part
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that this will work for the very next `Chapter` only. As you can see in the XML, there are multiple `Chapters`, so I want to move every single `Chapter` below `Part` to `Part`. If you notice, then `Part02` has only one Chapter because there is a new `Part03` after it so `Part03` is a new parent element now. All the elements containing Chapter will be a child of `Part03` from here on and as soon as an element comes that does not contain Chapter, it will be a new parent element again.

Comment: Please edit your question to indent the XML - and ideally remove irrelevant aspects that are making the question harder to read. For example, including `id="navPoint-" playOrder=""` in every element makes it harder to read - and I suspect you don't need `<navLabel><text>X</navLabel></text>` when just `X` would suffice - or at least `<text>X</text>`. (And is anything outside the `navMap` element relevant?)

Comment: @JonSkeet - Sorry for that. I have made the changes, hopefully it is much clearer now

Comment: Your first XML document is invalid. Can you please fix it?

Comment: I also don't understand the grouping you're after. Your second XML doesn't make that clear for me.

Comment: @Enigmativity - First XML fixed. Basically I want the `Chapters` to become a `child` of its previous `Part` element. As shown in the XML.

Comment: The output XML had become non-indented. Please check that the indentation I've applied is correct. It's also unclear to me whether the nesting in the original XML is relevant or not.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Sorry, I was re-indenting too. I hope mine is correct. I've made the two XML blocks consistent.

Comment: @JonSkeet - The nesting in the original is correct and is a requirement and so is the output XML. It's just that I am unable to achieve the one in the output XML.

Comment: The first half of the input XML is now the same as the first half of the output XML, as far as I can see. Is that intentional? Fundamentally this question is still *really* confusing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the question still isn't *very* clear to me, I *think* this does what you want:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var document = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
        var points = document.Descendants("navPoint").ToList();

        XElement currentPart = null;
        foreach (var point in points)
        {
            var src = point.Element("content").Attribute("src").Value;
            if (src.Contains("#Part"))
            {
                currentPart = point;
            }
            else if (src.Contains("#Chapter"))
            {
                if (point.Parent != currentPart)
                {
                    point.Remove();
                    currentPart.Add(point);
                }
            }
        }
        document.Save("output.xml");
    }
}
```

This assumes that:

- Every `navPoint` element has a `content` element with a `src` attribute
- There's always a part element before the first chapter element
- It's fine to just move chapter elements to the end within the current part element